# Redirection using header() not working properly while checking session

Tags: php, header

I have the problem with header..

I am working on login functionality... in that

1)If the user logged in with his/her credentials...

2)After that user try to open new tab and type the LoginViewController.php..

3)Here i need to redirect the user to previous logged in page..based on seesion active ..

4)But the header is not redirecting to loggedin.php page.. and showing some blank page..

```
 Here is the LoginViewController.php

 <?php
 session_start();
 include('GenericClasses/GenericCollectionClass.php');
 include('Models/UsersModel.php');
 include('DataObjects/Users.php');
 include('DatabaseAccess/DBHandler.php');

     if(!empty($_SESSION['user']))// Here checking session is empty or not
        {
            header("Location : loggedin.php");// Here it is not redirecting properly
            die();
        }
        else 
         {       

         }?>
```

Here is loggin.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: Fri, 4 Jun 2010 12:00:00 GMT");
  include('GenericClasses/GenericCollectionClass.php');
  include('Models/UsersModel.php');
  include('DataObjects/Users.php');
  include('DatabaseAccess/DBHandler.php');

      if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
         {
           header('Location: LoginViewController.php');
           exit();
          }
          echo '<div style="background:white; text-align:right"> Login  as:'.$_SESSION['user'].'<a href="LogoutViewController.php" style="text-align:right">Logout</a></div>';
         ?>


Any suggestions are acceptable...
```

Comment: format  your code properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didnt went through the code but at first glance to your question I can suggest you three things ..

1. `session_start()` should be first line after `<?php`
2. Make sure noting is getting outputted before `header()` . It won't work then.

   From [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

   ```
   Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, 
   either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
   ```
3. Try enabling output buffering using [`ob_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) after `session_start` and flush it in end using `ob_flush`

Answer (score 2):

`session_start();` should be the fist line. Also you can't do a redirect after any content has been output, this includes any trailing space from the included files.

Answer (score 0):

Put the session_start() on the top. It should be first on first line and remove unnecessary space from the code.